# Prevent HTML element to strip BODY tag when changing innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I'm trying to replace the innerHTML attribute of an HTML element with an entire HTML document (this element will be used to render an entire HTML page inside an iframe).

```
const container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = 
'<html>
  <body class="c1">
    <div class="c2">aaa</div>
  </body>bbb
 </html>';
```

If I examine container.innerHTML after this, I get:

```
<div class="c2">aaa</div>bbb
```

Which is not what I expect, as the body tag has been stripped out, and, what is worse, the styling (c1) of the body is gone.

How do I prevent this?

Comment: do you want to place an html document in the div of an html document? I do not believe that the javascript interpreters can accept this, there must be a directive from the W3C obliging them to refuse this kind of practice.

Comment: @MisterJojo you are right, that is the reason. Prob better approach is to use an HTML Document. If you post a response suggesting that, I'll accept it.

Comment: to my knowledge, iframe is the only element that accepts an html document